# How to download file (InputStream) from Microsoft graph APIs?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, resttemplate, sharepoint-api, microsoft-graph-files

I am following [Graph APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=java) to download a file from Sharepoint.

I tried this endpoint:
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive_id}/root:/{folder}/{file_name}:/content](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/%7Bdrive_id%7D/root:/%7Bfolder%7D/%7Bfile_name%7D:/content)

And to fetch `InputStream` using `restTemplate`:

```
 HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        httpHeaders.set(GraphConstant.AUTHORIZATION, TOKEN);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = new HttpEntity(httpHeaders);

String downloadEndPoint = DOWNLOAD_FILE_ENDPOINT.replace(GraphConstant.DRIVE_ID,getDriveId(id)).replace("{folder}",folder).replace(GraphConstant.FILE_NAME, URLEncoder.encode(fileName, GraphConstant.UTF_8).replace("+", "%20"));
        ResponseEntity<InputStream> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(downloadEndPoint,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                httpEntity,
                InputStream.class);

        if(responseEntity.getStatusCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK)){
           return responseEntity.getBody();

        }
```

`responseEntity.getBody()` returns `null`.

What is the return type of [Graph Download file API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=java)? Any inputs here?

I am using a SpringBoot application and making calls with restTemplate (not using Microsoft SDK to make graph calls).

Comment: For my scenario, i used the below code sample uses Java/GraphClient (not the springboot/resttemplate) and it worked:


IGraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider( authProvider ).buildClient();
 
Stream stream = graphClient.customRequest("/me/drive/items/01252UHI5DGSKWGHIUXBD3GPQWY7UT7TVN/content", Stream.class)
    .buildRequest()
    .get();

Comment: Are you still looking for help here?

Answer (score 1):

Changing ResponseEntity to ResponseEntity<byte[]> solved my problem.

```
ResponseEntity<byte[]> responseEntity = graphRestTemplate.exchange(DOWNLOAD_FILE_ENDPOINT,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            httpEntity,
            byte[].class,
            drive_id,
            entity_id,
            fileName);
```